# Objective C - Mapkit - Plot image in street with right orientation

Tags: image, mapkit

My question is quite hard to do, but let's go. 
I'm creating a App where the user is able to see some images plotted in the map. But what I don't know is how to plot something in the street with the right orientation.

Have you guys created something like that? The result is like a Taxi or Uber App, where user see cars plotted in the map pointed to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can look at.

1st MapKit - MapView - This will allow you to add maps in you app.
2nd MapKit - MKAnnotations - This will allow you to add annotations to your mapView. You can customize those annotation with car images.
3rd Image transformation - This will help you rotate images according to given directions.